# Set Background color Once for all Views | SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is there a way to assign background to all views once? This is what I'm currently doing:

```
NavigationView {
    ZStack {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    AssetsPickerView()
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    .setViewBackground()
}
```

If you notice I have to pass in the modifier for every view, in the code above AssetsPickerView() would not inherit the background color, how can I say once hey this is the background, use it for all views?

The code I'm using to set the background is:

```
extension View {
    
    func setViewBackground() -> some View {
        modifier( SetViewBackground() )
    }
}

struct SetViewBackground: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .background(Color("DarkBackground").ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .all))
    }
}
```

Thank you

EDIT:

lol I tried this:

```
extension View {
    init() {
        modifier( SetViewBackground() )
    }
}
```

but gives me an error: `self' used before 'self.init' call or assignment to 'self'`

Comment: Try setting it on the `NavigationView` vs the `ZStack`

Comment: That would work for this case but I would still need to pass in the same modifier for other views not there. Is there a way to apply it once?

Comment: It should apply to all `View`s in the `NavigationView`, I haven't tested it. Some exceptions would be `.sheet` and maybe `NavigationLink` but I am not sure.

Comment: I meant everything, beginning from @Main view and ending in all subviews

Comment: You cannot do this the way you want. This sounds like an XY-problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). What are you trying to achieve by setting the background for every view in your hierarchy?

Comment: I get what you are trying to do but it goes against SwiftUIs nature. I doubt you’ll find a one size fits all solution. There would be so much to compensate for.